# How to convert json file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have got `json` file and I don't know how to convert it.

I'm trying use `stringily` or `parse` but it doesn't work.

See my `json` data below:

```
  first: {
     'big': {
       'letter': 'let',
       'Can go walk': 'CGW',
       'something': 'smthg'
     },
     'low': {
       'call_me': 'call me',
       'just_do_it': 'just do it'
     }
}
```

I need to convert it to the following format:

```
  first: [{
     big: [
       {name: 'letter', value: 'let'},
       {name: 'Can go walk', value: 'CGW'},
       {name: 'something', value: 'smthg'}
     ],
     low: [
       {name: 'call_me', value: 'call me'},
       {name: 'just_do_it', value: 'just do it'},
     ]
}]
```

How can I convert from format 1 to format 2 (here I do some changes in object when it in format 2) and after format to 1

Comment: Neither of those are valid JSON (they are valid JS objects, but that's not the same thing!). If you're trying to parse the data from the first example, it'll fail, as `first` isn't wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @JoeClay I can add ' ' to first. But I must parse this values to table, but I don't know how because map not working with it, and I don't have name and value for example. How I can get my variables?

Comment: @Princeair Please look at the updated answer

Comment: As a reference, see https://www.json.org/ (A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.)

Comment: It is not ok to extend a question with another question, after initial answers have been posted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers

Answer (score 0):

The JSON standard is to use double quotes, JS's `JSON.parse()` function will now work with single quotes. Try this instead:

```js
var x = JSON.parse('{"big": {}, "low": {}}')

var arr = [x["big"], x["low"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (it's messy)

```js
const json = {
 first: {
   'big': {
    'letter': 'let',
    'Can go walk': 'CGW',
    'something': 'smthg'
   },
   'low': {
    'call_me': 'call me',
    'just_do_it': 'just do it'
   }
 }
}
let arr = [{}]
for (let prop_lv0 in json) {
 arr[0][prop_lv0] = [{}];
  for (let prop_lv1 in json[prop_lv0]) {
   arr[0][prop_lv0][0][prop_lv1] = [];
    for (let prop_lv2 in json[prop_lv0][prop_lv1]) {
     arr[0][prop_lv0][0][prop_lv1].push({ name: prop_lv2, value: json[prop_lv0][prop_lv1][prop_lv2] })
    }
   }
 }
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: after it how I can convert it to default state?

Answer (score -2):

```
    Jquery cs code:
    
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
            
        
                [WebMethod]
                    public string GetCountry()
                    {
                        string _data = "";
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_country_get",con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        con.Close();
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                        }
                        return _data;
                    }
            
            [WebMethod]
                    public void Insert(string A, int B, int C, string D)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_insert", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", A);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", B);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", C);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", D);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
            
            
            [WebMethod]
                    public void Delete(int ID)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_delete", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
            
            [WebMethod]
                    public string Edit(int ID)
                    {
                        string _data = "";
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_edit", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        con.Close();
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                        }
                        return _data;
                    }
            
            
            [WebMethod]
                    public void Update(int ID, string A, int B, int C, string D)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_update", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", A);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", B);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", C);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobbies", D);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
            
                [WebMethod]
                        public string GetEmployee()
                        {
                            string _data = "";
                            con.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_emp_get", con);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(ds);
                            con.Close();
                            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                            }
                            return _data;
                        }






aspx code:

Scripting :

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var IDD = "";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            CountryBind();
            //EmployeeBind();
        });

        function CountryBind() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'Employee.asmx/GetCountry',
                type:'post',
                contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType:'json',
                data:'{}',
                async: false,
                success: function (_dt) {
                    _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                    for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                        $("#ddlcountry").append($('<option/>').attr("value", _dt[i].cid).text(_dt[i].cname));
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('CountryBind error');
                }
            });
        }


        function SaveData() {
            var HOB = "";
            HOB = $('input:checkbox:checked.B').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            if ($("#btnsave").val()==("Save")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Employee.asmx/Insert',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: "{A:'" + $("#txtname").val() + "',B:'" + $("#ddlcountry").val() + "',C:'" + $('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val() + "',D:'" + HOB + "'}",
                    success: function () {
                        alert('insert success !!');
                        EmployeeBind();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('insert error !!');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Employee.asmx/Update',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: "{ID:" + IDD + ",A:'" + $("#txtname").val() + "',B:'" + $("#ddlcountry").val() + "',C:'" + $('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val() + "',D:'" + HOB + "'}",
                    success: function () {
                        alert('Update Successfully');
                        EmployeeBind();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Update error');
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        function EmployeeBind() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee.asmx/GetEmployee',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{}",
                async: false,
                success: function (_dt) {
                    _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                    $("#tbl").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    for (var i = 0; i < _dt.length; i++) {
                        $("#tbl").append('<tr><td>' + _dt[i].name + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].cname + '</td><td>' + (_dt[i].gender == "1" ? "Male" : _dt[i].gender == "2" ? "FeMale" : "Others") + '</td><td>' + _dt[i].hobbies + '</td><td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" onclick="EditData(' + _dt[i].id + ')" /><td><input type="button" id="btndelete" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteData(' + _dt[i].id + ')" /></td</tr>');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('EmployeeBind error');
                }
            });
        }

        function DeleteData(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee.asmx/Delete',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{ID:'" + id + "'}",
                success: function () {
                    alert('Delete Successfully');
                    EmployeeBind();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('DeleteData error');
                }
            });
        }

        function EditData(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Employee.asmx/Edit',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async:false,
                data: "{ID:'" + id + "'}",
                success: function (_dt) {
                    _dt = JSON.parse(_dt.d);
                    $("#txtname").val(_dt[0].name);
                    $("#ddlcountry").val(_dt[0].cid);
                    $("input[name=A][value=" + _dt[0].gender + "]").prop('checked', true);

                    var hbb = _dt[0].hobbies;
                    var arr = hbb.split(',');
                    $("input:checkbox:checked.B").prop('checked', false);
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        $("input:checkbox[class=B][value=" + arr[i] + ']').prop('checked', true);
                    }

                    $("#btnsave").val("Update");
                    IDD = id;
                    EmployeeBind();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('EditData error');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

Body:

<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtname" /></td>
    </tr>
        
    <tr>
        <td>Country :</td>
        <td><select id="ddlcountry">
                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Gender :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="A" value="1" /> male
            <input type="radio" name="A" value="2" /> female
            <input type="radio" name="A" value="3" /> other
        </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Hobbies :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="cricket" /> cricket
            <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="music" /> music
            <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="movies" /> movies
            <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="cooking" /> cooking
            <input type="checkbox" class="B" value="coding" /> coding
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="SaveData()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <table id="tbl" border="1" style="border-color:darkblue;width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Hobbies</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This very much does not look like an actual answer to this question, which is about Javascript and JSON conversion.